# Infinitely "deep" globular sets / categories

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

In the usual sense a globular set consists of objects, arrows between objects, 2-arrows between arrows, etc. having $n$-arrows for every $n \in \mathbb N$ (although some may be empty). A category (or an $(\infty,1)$-category for that matter) is a globular set with some additional structure.

Does anyone ever consider "infinitely deep" globular sets? In the sense that there are no objects, just an infinite chain of $n$-arrows for $n \in \mathbb Z$ which point between $(n-1)$-arrows? And if one were to form an "infinitely deep" category like this (yes the associativity isomorphism constraints are horrendously complicated), do the results of usual category theory even hold?

Comment: So something like a presheaf on the category with objects $\mathbb{Z}$ and morphisms $s,t : n \to (n-1)$ satisfying $ss = st$, $ts = tt$? There's no reason you couldn't consider that, but it's not quite clear what the "things" at level $-12$ would represent, for example... What did you have in mind?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I don't see how you are composing the morphisms $s$ and $t$, since neither's source is the other's target.

Comment: I omitted the indices for simplicity... If $s_n, t_n : n \to (n-1)$, then the relations are $s_n s_{n+1} = s_n t_{n+1}$, $t_n s_{n+1} = t_n t_{n+1}$. But now I have to ask... Do you know how globular sets (or globular categories) are defined?

Comment: Oh, I should have realized the obvious parallel. I apologize. Yes, that would be the appropriate construction. Anyhow, my intuition of such structures interprets the $(-12)$-arrows as arrows between $(-11)$-arrows. Just like the globular sets construction except you never get to "the final level of arrows" which in the usual globular construction would be the zero "level" (the objects).